# better practice for work with saved buffer

Tags: gtk, glib, gtk3

I am working on a `gtk_list_store`, that will save the rows to a file (`g_file_set_contents(file, buffer)`)
After saving the datas to a file, without exiting, I will like to edit the file (as buffer) again. For that I have 2 option in my knowledge:

1. save the data, g_free(buffer), list_store_clear, reload the saved
   file
2. save the buffer to the file, but continue working with that same buffer without
   g_free(buffer)

Both seems to work, but which is the better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is better.  1 just forces the computer to do extra work.